# Calling D3.JS function on 'load' rather than on mouse event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, nvd3.js

I am trying to make modifications to the D3 sankey example here:

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13

I want to shift the y-position of each node to a specified location (300px in the example below).

The most straight forward way I can to see to achieve this is to simply repurpose `dragmove()` to be called after the the SVG elements have been added. I've made changes to `d.y` in this function to shift to 300px:

```
  function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + d.x + "," + (
                d.y = 300
            ) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
  }
```

This function is called when adding the nodes:

```
  var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("dragstart", function() { 
      this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
      .on("drag", dragmove));
```

At present, it shifts to 300px as expected on the specified mouse event, but I want it to shift on its own after all the SVG elements have been added instead.

Simply using `.call()` without the mouse event doesn't work.

I've also tried to incorporate the shift in `var node` instead:

```
return "translate(" + d.x + "," + 300 + ")"; })
```

However this leads to a mismatch between the leads and the nodes, and calling `sankey.relayout()` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

First I removed `.call()` at the end of `var node`, as I don't need the drag event:

```
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Then I set d.y to the arbitrary location (300):

```
return "translate(" + d.x + "," + (d.y = 300) + ")"; });
```

Finally I forced it to re-draw the connecting links immediately after `var node`.

```
sankey.relayout();
link.attr("d", path);
```